# Why do I have to specify the outer namespace for a function in a nested anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Given a namespace A. Inside is an anonymous namespace with function f and a class X, also with function f: Why do I have to specify the outer namespace A:: as a qualifier when calling anonymous f from A::X::f?

As a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace A {

 namespace {
     int f( int i ) { return i; }
 }

 class X {
 public:
     static int f() { A::f( 10 ); }
 };

}


int main()
{
   cout << A::X::f() << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: N.B. the anonymous namespace is completely irrelevant here, Mike's answer is correct and notice that it doesn't say anything specific to anon namespaces. The same answer would still apply even if you removed the anon namespace and `f` was directly in namespace `A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, within the scope of `X::f`, the unqualified name `f` refers to `X::f`, not any other `f`. A name declared within a scope will hide anything with the same name in an outer scope.